# IE11: How to prevent sprite animating to correct co-ords

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, internet-explorer-11

As is customary, in the top-left of a website I've placed a company logo wrapped in a link to the homepage. This image belongs to a sprite, along with different sizes of the same image (amongst others).

The website has responsive CSS so the default background-image for the element in question is the smaller, mobile version, with a media-query selecting the larger version for desktop browsers.

However, when the page loads in Internet Explorer 11 you can see the larger version of the image being manoeuvred into position. In fact, it becomes very noticeable if you click on the icon to reload the homepage: the sprite appears to slide past the background-image 'window'. [I've found that the effect *doesn't* happen if you have IE's developer tools open.]

Furthermore, there are three  elements in the page's banner which have their font-sizes animated to the full size.

Does anyone know how to prevent this animation effect happening? Particularly with the sprite - because you can see the other graphics in the sprite quickly sliding past the 'window' - it just looks out of place.

To see the example first-hand, browse to [this site](https://www.supertext.ch/) with IE11.

Comment: If you don’t want a `transition` for a certain element and CSS property – the you should either not target that element with the rule that applies the `transition` (or reset it for that element again), or not use `transition:all …`

Comment: I hadn't realised that there *was* a transition property assigned to all anchor elements. Thanks for pointing this out, it stopped the problem. [If you had provided this suggestion as an answer rather than a comment then you'd receive more points.]

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want a `transition` for a certain element and CSS property – then you should either not target that element with the rule that applies the transition (or reset it for that element again), or not use `transition:all` …

(You had `a { transition:all; }` in your stylesheet, and so the change of `background-position` for your linked logo was transitioned as well, instead of happening “instantly”.)